# Library for video streaming from TV card connected to satellite

Tags: linux, library, video, streaming, server

I would like to build own video stream server. I have server with pci-e tv card and centos/ubuntu os. TV card is connected to satellite antenna. Could you tell me, What should I do to be able to manage channels through this tuner without having to use media players? Do you have some libraries for this? I know Nodejs, C++, Java and Python, so libs can be in those technologies.

Comment: So, you are looking for software, but if it does not exist yet you are OK with developing it, do I understand correctly?

Comment: Actually, I'm writting this software, But I wonderhow most convenient to manipulate TVCard. So, I'm asking for some lib to manipulate TVCard, or some documentation with can be helpful.

Comment: OK, so looking for a library only, thanks! Documentation is off-topic but libraries are definitely on-topic :-) What is the model of your TV card, just in case?

Comment: Model name is Cine s2 v7a